# Convert a Python script to a Sed script

Tags: python, awk, sed

To move from [Pelican](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/) to [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/). I need to rewrite some parts of my Markdown files.

The article headers, from this:

```
Title: Threads                                                                                                          
Date: 2017-03-08 04:30:25                                                                                               
Modified: 2017-03-08 03:40:17                                                                                           
Category: Unix                                                                                                          
Tags: c,                                                                                                                
Slug: an-overwiew-on-threads                                                                                            
Authors: Nsukami                                                                                                        
Summary: A long, thin strand of cotton, nylon, or other fibres used in sewing or weaving.                               
Lang: en
```

To this:

```
---                                                                                                                     
title: Threads                                                                                                          
date: 2017-03-08 04:30:25                                                                                               
lastmod: 2017-03-08 03:40:17                                                                                            
categories:  ['Unix']                                                                                                   
tags:  ['c',]                                                                                                           
slug: an-overwiew-on-threads                                                                                            
summary: A long, thin strand of cotton, nylon, or other fibres used in sewing or weaving.                               
---
```

And the internal links, from this:

```
[processes]({filename}/on-processes.md)
[Threads]({filename}/images/threads-example.gif)
```

To this:

```
[processes]({{< ref on-processes >}})
[Threads](/images/threads-example.gif)
```

I already have an Awk [script](https://paste.debian.net/hidden/051bcce0/) converting the headers. I also have this Python script, that I would like to rewrite using Sed, or maybe Awk (mainly for learning purpose):

```py
import os
import re
import sys
import glob
import shutil
from tempfile import mkstemp

def replace(file_path):
    #Create temp file
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with open(fh,'w') as new_file:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                # search for something like 
                # [this: processes]({filename}/on-processes.md)
                # or this: [Threads]({filename}/images/threads-example.gif)
                match = re.search( r'(?:!| )?((\[.*\])\((\{filename\})/(.*)\.(.*)\)(?:.|,| )?)', line, re.M|re.I)
                if match:
                    old_link = match.group(1)
                    if match.group(5).startswith("md"):
                        # if md file, replace by 
                        # [processes]({{< ref on-processes >}})
                        new_link = match.group(2)+'({{< ref '+match.group(4)+' >}})'
                    else:
                        # if image, replace by 
                        # [Threads](/images/threads-example.gif)
                        new_link = match.group(2)+'(/'+match.group(4)+'.'+match.group(5)+')'
                    line = line.replace(old_link, new_link)
                new_file.write(line)

        #Remove original file
        os.remove(file_path)
        #Move new file to old file
        shutil.move(abs_path, file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # for all md files in content folder
    for i, article in enumerate(glob.iglob("./content/post/*.*", recursive=True)):
        # replace all internals links
        replace(article)
```

I tried to used Sed, just to catch and print all the internal links that should be converted:

```
~/nskm
>> sed -n /^.*\[[[:alnum:]]\]\({filename}.*\)/p on-threads.md
```

```
I've written something about [processes]({filename}/on-processes.md). Let's write some notes about threads. This is not really an introduction
to threads. It's more like a little bit of introspection, so we can have an interesting perspective of what are threads.<br><br>              
Processes each have their own address space. Threads exist as subsets of a process. Threads are just multiple workers in the same [virtual address space]({filename}/on-processes.md#vas), all threads in a process share the same memory. They can also share open files and other resources. Within that VAS, each thread has its own ID, its own stack, its own program counter, its own independent flow of control, its own registers set. A thread is just a **context of execution**.<br>
![Threads]({filename}/images/threads-example.gif)
[Processes]({filename}/on-processes.md) are created with the [fork()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) system call. However, there is a separate system call, named [clone()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) which is used for creating threads. It works like fork(), but it accepts a number of flags for adjusting its behavior so the child can share some parts of the parent's execution context.
Our c script made a call to clone(), twice. And looking at _some_ of the flags that have been passed, we can see that:                        
![insert breakpoints]({filename}/images/insert-breakpoints.png)
![info proc mappings]({filename}/images/info-proc-map1.png)
![info proc mappings]({filename}/images/info-proc-map2.png)
![thread's stack]({filename}/images/stacks.png)
```

And I've also tried to catch all internal links to be converted, this time with Awk:

```
~/nskm
>> awk '/.*(filename}.*\..*)/' on-threads.md  # regex not precise enough
```

```
I've written something about [processes]({filename}/on-processes.md). Let's write some notes about threads. This is not really an introduction
to threads. It's more like a little bit of introspection, so we can have an interesting perspective of what are threads.<br><br>              
Processes each have their own address space. Threads exist as subsets of a process. Threads are just multiple workers in the same [virtual address space]({filename}/on-processes.md#vas), all threads in a process share the same memory. They can also share open files and other resources. Within that VAS, each thread has its own ID, its own stack, its own program counter, its own independent flow of control, its own registers set. A thread is just a **context of execution**.<br>
![Threads]({filename}/images/threads-example.gif)
[Processes]({filename}/on-processes.md) are created with the [fork()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) system call. However, there is a separate system call, named [clone()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) which is used for creating threads. It works like fork(), but it accepts a number of flags for adjusting its behavior so the child can share some parts of the parent's execution context.
Our c script made a call to clone(), twice. And looking at _some_ of the flags that have been passed, we can see that:                        
![insert breakpoints]({filename}/images/insert-breakpoints.png)
![info proc mappings]({filename}/images/info-proc-map1.png)
![info proc mappings]({filename}/images/info-proc-map2.png)
![thread's stack]({filename}/images/stacks.png)
```

I'm stuck on how to tell sed/awk to not just print, but this time, to replace those internal links. If possible, I also would like to make my sed regex and my awk regex more precise. Thanks for advices and suggestions on how to continue from this point.

Comment: Why you need to migrate it to sed/awk? Can't you make it exacutable and use as a command like sed/awk? What `replace` function does, in short?

Comment: It looks like you're replacing links inside markdown files by something else, but I'm not sure

Comment: To really be effective with our help, we need to see a small set of sample data (that covers any corner cases you have identified), required output from that same sample data, your current output and exact text of any error messages you encounter (and your code). Otherwise we have to play 20 questions with you. Please update your Q so we can help. Good luck.